# Hibernate Search index is not updated when entity is created or updated

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-transactions, hibernate-search

I'm using Hibernate Search 4.4.2.Final, manual indexing works okay - index files are created when using this code:

```
FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession());
fullTextSession.createIndexer(clazz).batchSizeToLoadObjects(75).threadsForSubsequentFetching(5).purgeAllOnStart(true).optimizeAfterPurge(true).optimizeOnFinish(true).cacheMode(CacheMode.NORMAL).startAndWait();
```

Index is not updated when entity is created/updated.

`org.hibernate.search.event.impl.FullTextIndexEventListener` is properly registered as an onPost* listener and my custom listeners are called, so I expect that FullTextIndexEventListener is also called. But I don't see added entity when inspecting it using Luke.

I don't want to use `hibernate.search.worker.batch_size = 1` as it's deprecated now.
I didn't set `hibernate.search.indexing_strategy = manual` .

I'm using Hibernate's sessionFactory.

What I have to do to have my entities indexed after they are created/updated?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you confirm the listeners are called? For once there should be a log message in the logs (if debug level is enable). Something along the lines "Hibernate Search event listeners deactivated/activated". You could also just debug the application and set a breakpoint. If the listener gets indeed called you should share more information about your setup and configuration. Also the code on how you create and update the entities might be interesting. How do you for example handle transactions? Does the database get properly updated?

Comment: I've implemented a code which asks index from my application and new entites are there. So everything works okay - only records in index created/updated after app start are not visible using Luke. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you checked your event listener and whether it is called?

Comment: Yes, it is. New entites are indexed and visible for my app so all is okay.

Comment: Could you report it on https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH and attach an example entity which triggers the problem? Ideally with an example code to see how you store it too?